# How do you get the correct type of class in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of instances from different classes.  I need to sort out which instances belong to which type. However I cannot get the `type` method to work the way I want

```
type(consec_notes[0])
<class 'music21.key.Key'>
type(consec_notes[0]) == 'music21.key.key'
False # should say True
type(consec_notes[0]) == "<class 'music21.key.Key>'"
False
```

Comment: Use the type itself to compare, don't use strings. This ain't JS

Answer (score 2):

You should better compare a type with his class

```
type(consec_notes[0]) == music21.key.Key
```

Answer (score -1):

get the class name by `consec_notes[0].__class__.__name__`

```
>> consec_notes[0].__class__.__name__ == "music21.key.Key"

    # should return True
```